# Is there a PKCS certificate format that signs ASCII data?

Tags: authentication, certificates

Is there a PKCS #x already out there that was designed to sign ASCII data and protect it from manipulation?  I was originally guided to PKCS #7, but based on posts here it looks like the data is not signed, just the CRL information.  Don't care about that.

Here is how I would like this to work:

- Establish a root key set + self-signed certificate
- Establish a second level of key pairs with certs signed by the root
- Create "certificates" with ASCII text in the body (signed by 2nd level)

Kind of like a protected config file.  Easy to read/parse, but verifiable.  Sorry for the poor description.  I really am new to security concepts and admit it.  I just want to know if I need to forget about PKCS and just code it myself or is there something already defined that would support this?  Seems to me simpler to code myself, but just in case...

Comment: What about using PGP (GPG on linux) to sign text files?

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I believe I could use PGP signing as you state.  I am trying to stick with openssl for this project.

Comment: Fair enough. It just seems like you're trying to make certificates do something they weren't designed for, which could lead to a very messy implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "certificate" by the definition used in cryptography is information about a cryptographic entity in a specific format and signed by a "certificate authority" or CA; X.509 is the most common type of certificate and the one used by PKCS#7 or its updated version CMS (and S/MIME, which is a thin wrapper on CMS). If you want to sign your own data, not special cryptographic certificate data, then you want **SignedData**, which is one of several options (with some suboptions too) in PKCS#7/CMS. The data doesn't need to be ASCII but if it is that's fine, and if it's *canonical* printable ASCII (no control characters except CRLF for line break) then you can use the "detached signature" suboption, which allows anyone to view the data part without any special tool (but you can't modify it without invalidating the signature). Having a root CA that issues certs for multiple entities that use those certs and their keys to sign and verify data is a **bog-standard use of PKCS#7/CMS**.

Note that PKCS#7 is sometimes used as a "carrier" for X.509 certificates and/or CRLs, but *no* user data. Certificates and CRLs are internally signed by the CA that issues them, and do not need or get additional protection. That is different from the SignedData case, where the user data needs and gets a signature added.

As per the comment, **PGP** format, implemented by GnuPG and a few competitors, has the same basic capabilities (and pretty much goals) as PKCS#7/CMS/SMIME: parties generate keypairs which *may* be certified or may be distributed and trusted by other means; parties then use a privatekey to sign (arbitrary) data that any recipient can verify using the publickey, *or* use a publickey (or several) to encrypt data that only the intended recipient(s) can decrypt using the privatekey(s). (PKCS#7/CMS calls the latter "enveloping" to distinguish it from other forms of encryption.)

There are technical **differences**: PKCS#7/CMS uses ASN.1 encoding (as does X.509) while PGP uses its own tagged packet structure; both usually use base64 "armor"; PGP identifies keys by a shortish hexadecimal id and parties usually by an email address, while X.509 and PKCS#7/CMS identifies keys by (usually) a hash and parties by a "Distinguished Name" structure that can be horribly complicated but in a situation you control you can make quite simple.

But the most visible difference is that PGP comes primarily as a commandline or GUI program that you run to do key-generation, signing, etc. PKCS#7/CMS is implemented by at least a few libraries and as part of some other programs like Microsoft Outlook, but the only standalone program I know is the commandline utility in OpenSSL, which after long evolution has some quirks that take a little getting used to. OTOH if you want *your* program(s) to read-and-verify the file (and possibly create-and-sign it also), the OpenSSL library API is mostly straightforward and reasonably well documented, if you are using C or C++ or anything that can call C. For Java there's a good 3rd-party library from BouncyCastle. MSDN says dot-NET has support. Anything else, make your question more specific.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I feel much better about the original source of the suggestion to use PKCS7.  I can tell that I need to do lots more research.  After going back to the original posts that caused my confusion I can see why I mis-interpreted them, but with your inputs they are now clear.

Answer (score 0):

PKCS#7 is now standardized by IEFT as CMS, [RFC5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652).